# Create a main Frame for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I made an app which contains lots of Pages. Each page consists of 2 parts: a same part (some grid, control and events etc.) shared among pages, and a separate part which includes different content for each page.

Now I want to know if I could use a "main frame" which contains the first part, and so I only need to create pages containing the second part (In universal app they got Frame.Navigate() but I don't know if WP8 has it or not).

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a `PhoneApplicationFrame` (called `RootFrame`) defined in your `App.xaml.cs`.

You can create a default style for it and add the shared stuff in its `ControlTemplate`.

The code below is from my app 627.AM. You can see I put the logo (`AnimatedLogoView`) in there so I don't need to duplicate them on every page.

```
    <Style TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationFrame">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationFrame">
                    <Border x:Name="ClientArea" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="800" >
                        <Border.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Name="ShowGlobalMessageAnimation"/>
                        </Border.Resources>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <views:AnimatedLogoView x:Name="Logo" />
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but my "static part" not only have a children control and animation, but also have other button, and click events ... so a style is not really enough for me :(

Comment: You should wrap them all in a user control, and then reference it inside the style. You see the `AnimatedLogoView` there? It's a user control that contains a number of animations within itself. :) You can of course have `Buttons` and click events defined in there too.

Comment: Uhm, "A frame integrates with the Windows Phone look and feel so that it appears like any other application. Only a single frame is available to the application with no exceptions." , -> using a Frame within Page is not allow in WP8, so UserControl is the only way ? Thanks :(

Comment: Yes, user control would be the only way I'm afraid.

Comment: @Romasz just sent you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a resource for the part you use on multiple pages. You can find some background on how to create resources on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh968442.aspx)